# Rsync files directories with different names

Tags: centos, rsync

I am trying to `rsync` files from a directory `incoming` to a directory called `outgoing`, i.e.,

```
/testcopy/folder1/incoming/test1.txt
```

to

```
/testdest/folder1/outgoing/
```

Directory source:

```
/testcopy/folder1/incoming/test1.txt
/testcopy/folder1/incoming/test2.txt
/testcopy/folder2/incoming/test1.txt
/testcopy/folder2/incoming/test2.txt
/testcopy/folder3/incoming/test1.txt
/testcopy/folder3/incoming/test2.txt
```

Directory destination:

```
/testdest/folder1/outgoing/
/testdest/folder2/outgoing/
/testdest/folder3/outgoing/
```

What I want the destination to look like:

```
/testdest/folder1/outgoing/test1.txt
/testdest/folder1/outgoing/test2.txt
/testdest/folder2/outgoing/test1.txt
/testdest/folder2/outgoing/test2.txt
/testdest/folder3/outgoing/test1.txt
/testdest/folder3/outgoing/test2.txt
```

The `rsync` script I have tried:

```
touch /testcopy/folder3/incoming/test4.txt
```

What I would expect to see is `test4.txt` file under the `/testdest/folder3/outgoing/`

```
# rsync -av /testcopy/*/incoming/* /testdest/*/outgoing/
sending incremental file list

sent 520 bytes  received 12 bytes  1,064.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I have tried a couple different iteration of the above script, but cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` does not allow rewriting of paths between source and destination.

What you could do instead is to call `rsync` once for each `/testcopy/*/incoming` directory:

```sh
for srcdir in /testcopy/*/incoming/; do
    [ ! -d "$srcdir" ] && break

    destdir=/testdest/${srcdir#/testcopy/}   # replace /testcopy/ with /testdest/
    destdir=${destdir%/incoming/}/outgoing/  # replace /incoming/ with /outgoing/

    mkdir -p "$destdir" &&
    rsync -av "$srcdir" "$destdir"
done
```

For each `incoming` directory, a destination path is constructed by replacing the `/testcopy/` path prefix with `/testdest/` and the `/incoming/` path suffix with `/outgoing/`.  This is done using two standard parameter substitutions.

The loop also creates the destination directory just in case it does not already exist.

The `[ ! -d "$srcdir" ] && break` at the start of the loop makes sure that the `mkdir` and `rsync` isn't run if the pattern does not match anything (the shell would by default leave the pattern unexpanded, unless you're in `zsh`).  In `bash`, you may want to use `shopt -s nullglob` instead, before the loop.

Comment: Thank you one question, is this line "mkdir -p "$destdir" &&" recreating the the  /testdest/ directory?

Comment: @RonRussey Only if it does not already exist.  If any of the directories in the path `/testdest/folder1/outgoing` was missing, the `rsync` command would fail to copy the contents of `/testcopy/folder1/incoming` into it.